# Why there is an redundant variable debugInit in java.security.AccessControlContext?

Tags: java, java-security, java-security-manager

I was going through [java.security.AccessControlContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/security/AccessControlContext.java), and encountered below piece of code:

```
private static boolean debugInit = false;
private static Debug debug = null;

static Debug getDebug()
{
    if (debugInit)
        return debug;
    else {
        if (Policy.isSet()) {
            debug = Debug.getInstance("access");
            debugInit = true;
        }
        return debug;
    }
}
```

**Question:** why do we need an additional variable `debugInit`, when we can simple check for `if (debug == null)` and `getInstance()` like below:

```
static Debug getDebug()
{
    if (debug == null && Policy.isSet()) {
        debug = Debug.getInstance("access");
    }
    return debug;
}
```

Am I missing something or is there any specific reason to use additional variable `debugInit` (which is not referenced anywhere else) ?

Comment: to make sure that `Debug.getInstance("access");` is only called once

Comment: `debugInit` is set to `true` only when an instance of `debug` is created. So `if (debug == null && Policy.isSet())` also holds good in that case.

Comment: What if the `Debug.getInstance("access")` return null?